# Throwing a NullPointerException in C++

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception, nullptr

Is it possible to let C++ throw a NPE when calling a method on a nullptr object, instead of going in undefined behaviour? I could create a handler for a SEGFAULT signal but this would be realy dangerous, because not every SEGFAULT is a NullPointerException. If i have to do it via just checking in an if clause, is there a efficiant way to do so? Maybe also on compiletime?

Comment: Certainly possible, the question is, is it useful? Are you trying to debug something? Can your program still be useful in some way even if it needs to dereference a null pointer?

Comment: I am trying to code a small programming language and since I compile to c++, but dont wont to have undefined behaviour I would like to know how I could handle this

Comment: There's no such thing as a "nullptr object". Either you have an object, or you don't. If you don't, then you can't call member functions on an object, because you don't have an object to call a member function on.

Comment: Why is checking for null inefficient?

Comment: Writing a program in c++ where a null pointer exception is even a remote possibility indicates that there is a logic error in the design. Why would you create a pointer that pointed to no object?

Comment: If your pointer should never be null then you should be using references rather than pointers (they are guaranteed to never be null).

Comment: Calling a method on a `null` object is always undefined behavior in C++. There could be compiler-specific extensions that throw an exception when this occurs, but there is no standard-conformant way to achieve that. You should check for `null` before calling an object on a pointer, if there is a possibility that the pointer will be `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can but its not really a good idea (you should not be handling pointers anyway, in modern C++ pointers are held inside objects that manage their lifespan).

You can always define a class that holds the pointer. Then when you try and use `operator->()` it will throw if the held pointer is `nullptr`.

```
template<typename T>
class ThrowingUniquePtr
{
     T*   ptr;
     public:
        // STUFF to create and hold pointer.

        T* operator->()
        {
            if (ptr) {
                return ptr;
            }
            throw NullPointerException; // You have defined this somewhere else.
        }
};

class Run
{
    public:
        void run() {std::cout << "Running\n";}
};
int main()
{
    ThrowingUniquePtr<Run>    x(new Run);
    x->run();  // will call run.

    ThrowingUniquePtr<Run>    y(nullptr);
    y->run();  // will throw.
}
```

Comment: C++17 introduces the std::optional<T> class which provides the same functionality (via the std::bad_optional_access exception).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of exception handling:
   calling a function using NULL pointer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

char str_NullPointer[25] = "NULL Pointer exception";
char str_Arithmetic[25] = "Arithmetic exception";

class A
{
public:
   int i = 20; 
public:
    int function()
    {
        printf("Function start\n");

         try
        {
            if (this)
            {
                printf("value of i = %d \n", i);  
            }
            else
            {
                throw str_NullPointer;          /* Exception thrown in Case 2 */
            }
        }
        catch(const int s)
        {
            printf("%d\n", s);
        }
        catch(const char* s)
        {
            printf("%s in %s\n", s, typeid(this).name());  /* Exception and Class Name */
        }

        printf("Function end\n\n\n");
    }
};

int main() {
    //code

printf("Case 1: With Pointer\n");
A *obj = new A();
obj->i = 20;
obj->function();

printf("Case 2: With NULL Pointer\n");
delete obj;
obj = NULL;
obj->function();

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Case 1: With Pointer
Function start
value of i = 20 
Function end


Case 2: With NULL Pointer
Function start
NULL Pointer exception in P4abcd
Function end
```